# is it possible to call intranet site api from internet site using ajax request

Tags: javascript, cross-domain

We have a requirement to connect a intranet api from internet site using ajax call but if we try it throws access denied error. Is it possible to connect like this, thanks for you help in advance

Comment: Did you try Googling it? Learn about CORS.  And be careful not to open your intranet to arbitrary attackers.

Comment: Even with CORS, are you happy with putting functionality out on a public website that's broken for anyone outside of the building? I wonder if you think you can chain the information to the outside world this way. You need something server-side to solve either problem.